# How to optionally repeat a program in python

Tags: python, loops, python-2.x

I'm learning python and had a quick question.

I have to write a code to find the cube root, which I've done. 
I want to give the user the option of calculating another cube root, or quitting.

Here's what I have come up with:

```
x = int(raw_input('Enter an integer:   '))

## start guessing with 0 
ans = 0

while ans*ans*ans < abs(x):
    ans = ans + 1
    print 'current guess =', ans

print 'last guess = ', ans
print 'ans*ans*ans = ', ans*ans*ans


##if its a perfect cube

if ans*ans*ans == abs(x):
## perfect, but negative
    if x<0:
            ans = -ans
    print 'Cube root of ' + str(x)+ ' is ' + str(ans)

## If its not a cube at all    
else:
    print x, 'is not a perfect cube'



## Now to start a new calculation
again = raw_input('Find another perfect cube? (Y/N)')

if again == "N":
    quit
if again == "Y":
```

what would go next, in case the person wants to do another problem and chose "Y"?

Comment: You can just put everything inside a function, and run the function again.

Comment: i'm still pretty new to programming, how exactly would i be able to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all inside a function:

```
def my_func():
   x = int(raw_input('Enter an integer:   '))

   ## start guessing with 0 
   ans = 0

   while ans*ans*ans < abs(x):
       ans = ans + 1
       print 'current guess =', ans

   print 'last guess = ', ans
   print 'ans*ans*ans = ', ans*ans*ans


   ##if its a perfect cube

   if ans*ans*ans == abs(x):
   ## perfect, but negative
       if x<0:
             ans = -ans
       print 'Cube root of ' + str(x)+ ' is ' + str(ans)

   ## If its not a cube at all    
   else:
       print x, 'is not a perfect cube'



   ## Now to start a new calculation
   again = raw_input('Find another perfect cube? (Y/N)')

   if again == "N":
       quit
   if again == "Y":
       my_func()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_func()
```

Comment: I would call the function something other than `all` because `all` is a python builtin function.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the function route, you could do it in a while loop, though it would be cleaner to use functions. You could do:

```
choice = 'y'
while choice.lower() == 'y':
    #code for the game
    choice = raw_input ('run again? (y/n)')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also another way, similar to @xgord answer.
Use a a while loop. What i wrote is longer but simpler to me

```
repeat = False
while not repeat:
      # game code

play = input("Play again? (y/n)")
    if play == "y":
        repetition = False
    else:
        exit()
```